# find contours in image where object and background have nearly same color

Tags: python, opencv, contour, edge-detection

How could you perform efficiently edge detection when the object in the image and background have nearly same color?
I tried with the code below but it doesn't give what I want:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread("image1.JPG")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 150)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

plt.imshow(edged)
plt.show()
```

image1[image: image1]

edges1[image: edges detected]

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't convert the image to grayscale using `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, that's losing the color data. What you want to do is to find the color space that gives you the best edge detection results. There are 3 color spaces you can try and probably one would work fine for your application, HSV, YCrCb, and LAB.

Here is the result of canny edge detection on the second component of the LAB image.

[image]
[image]

```
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
a_component = lab[:,:,1]
edged = cv2.Canny(a_component, 10, 50)
```

Comment: His idea is correct. Moreover, you can build the optimal separation color transformation function based on two color model

Comment: @fireant thanks but I can't reproduce same result as yours! did you miss copying some lines of the code? Also, I want to detect the whole lighter not only the body part!

Comment: @MohammedGh That's the only 3 lines processing the input image, `img` is the array returned by `imread()`, and then `edged` is passed to `imwrite()` to get the left picture above. For detecting the other part of the lighter if you experiment with other color channels you will see there is a color channel that works perfect for that. Then you can combine the two channels to get borders of the lighter.

Comment: Is there a way to choose automatically the adequate color space (HSV, YCrCb, or LAB.)?